# APIGEE: Generate never expiring accesstoken

Tags: oauth-2.0, apigee

I have created a collection in APIGEE BaaS and now am exposing an API which mashes up data from this collection and also from other backend service. While calling the backend service from API, I am using an accesstoken. However, by default the expiry time for the accesstoken is set to 604800 milliseconds. I tried changing the default ttl using below API call,

PUT: `https://api.usergrid.com/<myorg>/<myapp>?client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret> {"accesstokenttl":0}`

It gives me a response as below, which seems to indicate that the request went through.

```
"uri": "https://api.usergrid.com/<myorg>/<myapp>",
"entities": [
    {
        "uuid": "93495580-ed20-11e3-89d5-25d72fde3d7e",
        "type": "application",
        "name": "<myorg>/<myapp>",
        "created": 1402020991714,
        "modified": 1402535205960,
        "accesstokenttl": 0,
```

However, when I try to get a new accesstoken using below request it still shows expiry set to  604800 milliseconds.

POST: `https://api.usergrid.com/<myorg>/<myapp>/token {"grant_type":"client_credentials", "client_id":<client_id>, "client_secret":<client_secret>`

Gives me following response:

```
{
"access_token": "UREDStK1padfdffayGfNfoYtCiAAAAUaxsjHnfhkLkG1abYWVPC_MMWD3VFRaHyA",
"expires_in": 604800,
```

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You've updated your max token expiry at the application level correctly (to summarize):

```
PUT: https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/?client_id={app_client_id}&client_secret={app_client_secret}
```

With the JSON payload (don't forget to set the `Content-Type: application/json` header!)

```
{
   "accesstokenttl":31104000000
}
```

Where the tokenttl is a timestamp in milliseconds (or non-expiring, as you did in your example).

What you need to do now is actually set the TTL property on the token call:

```
POST https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/token 

{
    "username":"{username}", 
    "password":"{password}", 
    "grant_type":"password", 
    "ttl":"31104000000"
}
```

Here's a link to the [Apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-users-and-application-clients) that discusses token TTLs in detail.

Comment: I tried to set the ttl to 0 using https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/token  but still it gives me the same response - "{
"access_token": "UREDStK1padfdffayGfNfoYtCiAAAAUaxsjHnfhkLkG1abYWVPC_MMWD3VFRaHyA",
"expires_in": 604800,"

Comment: Try setting it to a large number like 31104000000 (1 year).

Comment: Hrm... double check the user/pass just to make sure? Never seen that error unless it's actually bad user/pass.

Comment: If I give a fairly large value like 31104000000, it gives me an error saying {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid username or password"
}. However if I set it to 311040000 (=above value / 100), it sets the expiry as below: {
    "access_token": "ABCEDEFFi8PHuO_pu9cr9aaQQAAAUag-y8ZuepPiYmXCSeUY7rUqhChgq2FRJs",
    "expires_in": 311040,

Comment: Ok in that case I don't think your app level TTL is set correctly.